# Possible MySQL sudden error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

**Hello friends from SO!**

Alright, this time I have a little bit more complex problem. We have a web crawler running and functioning normally during most of the day and time.

However, from time to time, it just stops: the link which is supposed to be analyzed next, never change it's state (from pending to scanning), and of course this stops the whole cycle.

**We're logging all PHP errors using:**

```
//errores producción
@ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
@ini_set('log_errors','On');
@ini_set('display_errors','Off');
@ini_set('error_log','/var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/xxx.com/xxx');
```

**There's no evidence of anything that could cause the problem described. 0 anomalies.**

Therefore, I believe the problem might be related to some kind of **MySQL issues?**

Every single MySQL query we do, is done using MySQLi by custome made functions, so my question here is:

---

### Is there any simple approach to record every single MySQL error on the same file where we are storing the PHP errors?

---

Here are some of the functions used to query the MySQL:

```
Function db_ob($db_link, $ask) {
$feedback = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($db_link, $ask));
return $feedback;
}
```

and:

```
Function db_ob_all($db_link, $ask) {
$feedback = mysqli_query($db_link, $ask);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($feedback)) { $value[] = $row; }
return $value;
}
```

---

So what I'm looking for, is a one or two lines solution, that I could add into these functions, in order to store and track any issue or error in the same file where I'm currently storing the PHP errors.

**Thanks in advance!
Chris;**

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

1) make a function to track the errors into the PHP error_log:

```
Function informar_error_db($db_link) {
error_log("Dreadful SQL error: ". mysqli_error($db_link)." in ".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
}
```

2) If there's MySQLi issues, save em:

```
Function db_ask($db_link, $ask) {
$feedback = mysqli_query($db_link, $ask);
if (mysqli_error($db_link)) { informar_error_db($db_link); }
return $feedback;
}
```

Here:
    **if (mysqli_error($db_link)) { informar_error_db($db_link); }**